# Accessing a variable declared in a project's gradle.properties file in a sub project's build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project that contains multiple sub gradle projects.

Within the sub projects `build.gradle` file, I would like use a plug in version variable that I have declared in the root project's `gradle.properties`. This way, I can update the version once globally and it will apply to all of the subproject's plug ins.

I can get this to work if I create a `gradle.properties` file in the subproject and declare the variable there, but that would defeat the purpose.

app1 build.gradle:

```
plugins {
        id 'application'
        id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version "${javaFXVersion}"
}
```

some-apps gradle.properties:

```
javaFXVersion = 0.0.8
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
some-apps/
    app-category/
               app1/
                   src/
                   build.gradle
                   gradlew
                   gradlew.bat
                   settings.gradle
                   gradle/
                   *.gradle
               app2/
                ...
                  
 build.gradle
 gradlew
 gradlew.bat
 settings.gradle
 gradle.properties
 gradle/
 *.gradle
```

Thanks!

Comment: All properties defined in the root project `gradle.properties` file are visible from all subprojects as well.  But in your case you will have another issue: you cannot apply a plugin in a subproject with a version different from the one applied in the root project (you will get error `Error resolving plugin [ ...] > Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version` ).

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks for your reply. My root project's `build.gradle` file actually does not contain a plugin, just a `wrapper` block.                                                                
                                                                                                                                         If I try to access the javaFXVersion variable I get an error: `Could not get unknown property 'javaFXVersion' for object of type org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.PluginRequestCollector$PluginDependenciesSpecImpl.`

Comment: I missed this in your initial quesiton:  you cannot use variables in the `plugins { }` bloc, due to Gradle limitation : see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax

Comment: hopefully you have another way to set plugin version from variables : see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management .

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I found that if I made a subproject level `gradle.properties` file, I could use `"${javaFXVersion}"` with the plugin. By extension, I should be able to access the variable from a project level `gradle.properties` file with something like `"${project.javaFXVersion}"`? Alternatively, could I use a plugin management at the subproject level, then use a variable defined at the project level? Thanks!

Comment: there is something wrong with your project layout : this seems  not a valid multi-project build : you should only have one `settings.gradle` and a single `wrapper` directory at the root level (`some-apps`) and then all subprojects, included in the root project `settings.gradle`.  Here, it looks like subprojects are (or can be) interpreted as standalone projects, this might explain why you cannot refer to root project properties. please try to follow this guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html